# Creating dynamic form inout fields with dynamic ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON object in controller and I want to generate dynamic input fields using ng-repeat.

```
$scope.keyValuePairs = [
    {id:""},
    {type:""},
    {brand:""},
    {category:""},
    {subCategory:""},
    {division:""}
];
```

And in template

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col-desktop mdl-cell--8-col-tablet" 
    ng-repeat="keyValue in keyValuePairs track by $index">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label full-width" 
        ng-repeat="(key,value) in keyValue">
        <input type="text" id="{{key}}" class="mdl-textfield__input" ng-model="eanForm[key]" 
            name="{{key}}"ng-required="true"/>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="{{key}}">Enter {{key}}</label>
        <span class="mdl-textfield__error" ng-show="eanForm.id.$dirty && 
            eanForm.id.$invalid" for="{{key}}">{{key}} required</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create dynamic ng-models so that I can give user privilege to add or delete form fields. How can I bind form fields to dynamic models ?

Comment: And what exactly is not working with what you currently have?

Comment: @David When I submit my form, eanForm object is empty.

Comment: @David Sorry, my bad. I was using eanForm instead of $scope.eanForm in controller.Deleting this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
$scope.fields = [];
$scope.addFields = function() {
    var maxId = getMax($scope.fields, "id");
    var id = maxId ? maxId + 1 : 1;

    $scope.fields.push({
        id: id,
        key: "",
        value: ""
    });
};

$scope.removeField = function(index) {
    if(!index || index < 0) return;

    $scope.fields.splice(index, 1);
}

function getMax(arr, prop) {
    var max;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!max || parseInt(arr[i][prop]) > parseInt(max[prop])) max = arr[
            i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    Field name: <input type="text" id="{{field.id + 'key'}}" ng-model="field.key" />

    Field Value: <input type="text" id="{{field.id + 'value'}}" ng-model="field.value" />
</div>
```

Comment: This will do the work but why cant we attach key name to model directly ?